# Request sign-off does not appear to users who have add/edit permission on library

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, power-automate, sharepoint-permissions

I have enabled the **Request sign-off** power automate in the document library (Modern); users with full-control are able to see this Power Automate but users with *Add/Edit permissions* (created a custom permission level - Content Creator, not given delete permissions) are not able to see this.

Do I need to give **Delete** permission to users to see/use **Request sign-off Power Automate**?
[image]
My requirement is *Content Creator (with Add Item/ Edit Item permissions)* can initiate the Requests Sign-Off for the selected item.

Comment: Please add the screenshot of the custom "Add/Edit permissions" permission level.Normally, contribute permission level is available to use flow(which include Request sign-off ).

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have created a custom permission level - "Content Creator", assigned/checked all list permissions except - delete and approve. Added a screenshot for more details. As you mentioned contribute access level - that means add/edit/detete item permissions

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, this is the OOB behavior that only when we have "Delete items" list permission, we can see Request sign-off option in SharePoint online.

I don't think your requirement could be achieved.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes, I also observed the same during implementation. Do you have any Microsoft article link where it's mentioned - to use Required Sign Off "Contribute" access or "add/edit/delete" permissions are MUST...

Comment: Per my research, there is no detailed information about this, we suggest you raise a support ticket to Microsoft to find more information.